# Is there a list of all the frameworks and libraries available for Erlang anywhere?

Tags: erlang

Is there a list of all the frameworks and libraries available for Erlang anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a project crawler at [trapexit](http://projects.trapexit.org/).